# after push data to mysql, the columns type (in DB) become default <text>

Tags: mysql, pandas, longtext

I created mysql DB, then i changed some variables types to "longtext", then i created dataframe in pandas, and pushed that df to DB

```
df.to_sql("my_table_name", conn, index=False, if_exists = 'replace')
```

this command insert data to DB but the variables types become default `text`.

Comment: there is an argument for `dtypes` in `to_sql` you can pass in a dictionary of your column names and types. what engine are you using `sqlalchemy`?